# Rename "Recently view products"

Tags: magento

I would like to rename "Recently view products" to "Recently view".
[image]
Can you please guide me where to look? Magento database is huge, so any ideas?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this by adding a locale folder with a region-appropriate subfolder which contains a file named translate.csv to your custom theme, e.g.

```
app/design/frontend/your_pkg/your_theme/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

where `en_US` is the language setting you've set in the admin for your store. This plain-text file should have the following line in it: `"Recently Viewed Products","Recently Viewed"`

You will need to refresh the translation cache after doing this.

Comment: There is also [inline translations](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-in-line-translations/)